# Can Authorize.net be used twice when setting up a payment processor?

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

We're in the process of setting up payment processor(s) in CiviCRM (v. 5.62.1), and are wondering if we can use the same ***Payment Processor Type*** (Authorize.net) more than once? The client has 2 Athorize.net accounts (used for different/specific purposes & and linked to specific, individual bank accounts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up multiple payment processors of the same payment processor type.